# How to fetch all users, but from each user data in firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am creating a hybrid app using firebase web settings.

This is an app for restaurants and the idea is that the user can do orders being at the restaurant and this order goes to a panel in the kitchen. I am using vue.js and when the user picks up an order, it is inserted into a store in VUEX called `orderingNow = [ ]`

This user is logged in and I have access to the user id.

In my db I have the followings refs:

```
ref('orders')
ref('users')
ref ('products')
```

The ref users there is just user basic info, like name, i inserted it when the user signs up.

ref products there are all the products and they are in this format:

```
{
  productName: 'Ice cream',
  qtd: null,
  id: 223232
}
```

Ref orders there are objects containing the userId, theOrderid and theProduct id, ike this:

```
{
       productId: 'dde',
       userId: 7,
       orderId: 'dsdfa'     
}
```

what i need to do is, when the user sends the order, this order should go to somewhere on firebase and the kitchen needs to filter the orders for each user.

I have been searching and thinking how to it for weeks, but i cant find any solution.

Can you tell me if its correct so far? I mean 3 refs and the refs should be organised the way I did so far?

so far I am stuck in to this.
someone can help me with some logic for that?

Comment: What's the problem you have with your current data structure? What use-case are you trying to implement on top of it, and struggling with? And what code did you write for that use-case already?

Comment: Acctually i havent wrote any code yet because i dont know the correct logic. I have the user logged in. And i just want to create a logic to send the users orders to database and display the orders from each user in some page which will be the KITCHEN of the restaurant.

Comment: Another man just told me i should create 3 refs.
1 for the user
1 for all the products 
1 for the orders

and the refs with the order should have the userId, productId and orderId.

Then i should fetch the orders with the products according to the userId, but i really cant imagine how to do it.